# which the best replacement for the "Wininet.dll"?

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following Methods of the "Wininet.dll"  to do the FTP UPLOAD by using vb.net application.

```
InternetOpen 
InternetConnect 
FtpGetFile 
FtpPutFile 
FtpSetCurrentDirectory 
FtpCreateDirectory 
FtpRemoveDirectory 
FtpDeleteFile 
FtpFindFirstFile 
InternetFindNextFile 
InternetGetLastResponseInfo
```

I would like to remove all the Methods of the "Wininet.dll"  and try to use the lastest dll ( which is capable for FTPS)

could you suggest which one is suitable for vb.net application?

I would like to use `FTPS` instead FTP. so i tried to use the `FLUENTFTP.dll` from the nuget package and able to use the FTPPUTFILE method successfully.

I would like to remove all the methods of "`Wininet.dll`" 
and try to use the latest DLL which is compatible for the FTPS.

Comment: Do you have any Issue/Error? Using FluentFtp isn't working for you? Can you share some code?

Answer (score 1):

Why exactly do you want to use the methods of the "Wininet.dll" in VB.NET to begin with? The .NET Framework already provides you with the necessary functions for doing a FTP upload. Please have a look at [FtpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-upload-files-with-ftp).
For using SFTP instead of FTP I suggest using [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#vbnet).

Comment: I am migrating the Legacy Windows application, so i must not use the web components. Any idea on this ?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you not allowed to use FtpWebRequest?